# Modifying .htaccess for get url params and issue with subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have a problem with my .htaccess.

I need to get url params like www.domain.com/param1/param2/param3 with Slim Framework. This works fine with this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]  
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
```

But when I try to enter in a subdomain like admin.domain.com I have problems with all referal objects like images, CSS, JS incrusted into my index.php .

Thank you for your time!